# How to get a particular key value pair from a dict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like below

```
d = {"a":0,"b":1,"c":2}
```

I need to get only this in my output dict

```
out = {"b":1}
```

tried converting the dict to list and accessing the index 1, but it gives me tuples.
Is there any workaround for this

```
print(list(d.items())[1])
("b",1)
```

Comment: Rebuild the dictionary with tuple.

Comment: you are nearly there, the `dict(...)` constructor function will accept a list of `(key, value)` tuples, so you can make a new dict by: `dict([list(d.items())[1]])`

Comment: dict([list(d.items())[1]])

Answer (score 0):

You could do `out = {elem:d[elem] for idx,elem in enumerate(d) if idx in [0,1]}` to select the indexes in `[0,1]` but `dict([list(d.items())[1]])`, as metioned by @Anetropic, works fine as well.

Comment: Hi, how do I get the multiple items at once knowing the index like out = {"b":1,"c":2}

Comment: Why traverse instead of `{'b': d['b']}` ?

Comment: @MechanicPig good point, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the source of your key value? If you want to get all the items in dictionary from a key container:

```
>>> keys = ['b', 'c']
>>> {key: d[key] for key in keys}
{'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

If you just want to get it in order from `d.items()`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> dict(islice(d.items(), 1, 3))
{'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```